# PC starts lagging about 1 minute after starting up

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, performance, lag

I have noticed my PC (mostly the web browser) is very sluggish recently. Using Windows 10, both Chrome and Firefox.

It feels like it's not much responsive - taking any action e.g. pressing any button on a website has always some lag/delay and is very uncomfortable. What exactly is lagging?

- swapping between browser tabs
- swapping between facebook chats (nightmare)
- occassionally typing is slow
- pressing Windows/Start button has noticable delay and some FPS issues

Pages are also loading slow, but rather in a JavaScript-sense, not related to the internet download speed sense (downspeed is fine). For example maximizing/minimizing YouTube video window has a delay like 2 seconds instead of normal expected 0.1-0.5 seconds.

CPU i5-4670k, RAM and Disks usage is fine. Same about temperatures.

I ran CrystalDiskInfo diagnostic tool and it says my SSD (120 GB) and HDD (1 TB) are in a good health.

Windows RAM diagnostic didn't find any issues.

---

**Important:** after booting up, for the very first minute of the work time, there are no lags at all! The facebook, youtube etc. are working flawlessly. Problem is starting about 1 minute after starting up the desktop.

Does this indicate a virus? Windows full-scan didn't find anything.

Normally I would wipe everything and re-install Windows but I want to avoid doing that.

Comment: Does task manager / resource monitor / process explorer show any processes hogging the CPU? (Maybe post some screenshots?)

Comment: The CPU is usually at few % e.g. 2% idle state. RAM usage around 2.5 GB, so I assume it's as normal as it gets. I'd post a screenshot but processes names aren't in english.

Comment: Hello. What is the video card you are using? Did you check GPU temps?

Comment: I am using GTX 760 2 GB which is a bit old by now, however please do keep in mind that the problem has appeared over several days/weeks and it used to be all fine before. GPU temp is about 40-45 Celcius, CPU is about 35-45. I am not stressing the PC with games or demanding programs.

Comment: Post your complete system specs please.

Comment: SSD: 60 GB (thought 120), HDD 1TB 5400rpm, MOBO: ASRock Z87 Extreme 4, CPU i5-4670k without oc, GPU GTX 760 2 GB, 8 GB DDR 3 1333 or 1600 MHz and 550 W power supply.

Comment: The software says the SSD/HDD are fine (health: 61% - good), but they have about 5.5 years of uptime... Perhaps this is an issue? But still software says hard drives are in a good shape. The issue started about 2 weeks ago and was never a problem.

Comment: Oops, the HDD is 7200rpm, not 5400rpm. The SSD 60 GB has about 6-7 GB free space. Windows and main programs like Chrome are on SSD.

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding important information in comments.

Comment: If you've only got 2% idle, what is the other 98% being taken up with?